# Debugging UFW and Samba on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, samba, ufw

I have two Ubuntu servers with identical Samba configs and same UFW rules for Samba's ports but the difference is that one with 14.04 works just fine and the other with 12.04 denies access from everywhere.

When UFW is disabled on the 12.04 server Samba connections are allowed again. Though, when UFW is enabled there are no log entries from the blocks in UFW's logs.

How could I debug this problem?

**Edit:** I found these `iptables` rules which are used for `smb` and `dhcp` ports:

```
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
```

However, removing them from `/etc/ufw/after.rules` did nothing.

Here is the current `iptables-save` output:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:fail2ban-apache - [0:0]
:fail2ban-apache-noscript - [0:0]
:fail2ban-apache-overflows - [0:0]
:fail2ban-dovecot - [0:0]
:fail2ban-postfix - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh-ddos - [0:0]
:fail2ban-wuftpd - [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,143,220,993,110,995 -j fail2ban-dovecot
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j fail2ban-postfix
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,20,990,989 -j fail2ban-wuftpd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-overflows
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-noscript
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A fail2ban-apache -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-noscript -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-overflows -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-dovecot -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-postfix -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh-ddos -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-wuftpd -j RETURN
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m state --state INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Apache%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Bind9\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Bind9\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Dovecot%20IMAP\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Dovecot%20POP3\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_OpenSSH\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Postfix\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Postfix%20SMTPS\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Postfix%20Submission\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m multiport --dports 137,138 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Samba\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 139,445 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Samba\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Firewall rules for the system that isn't working

Comment: There is now some additional information.

Comment: have you compared this set of rules to the set that works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the hood, UFW is just directing iptables/netfilter so the usual rues apply.

The first rule a [packet matches](https://serverfault.com/search?q=iptables%20first%20wins) against wins.

> and same UFW rules for Samba's ports

Your SMB related packets are likely matching an earlier rule that is blocking access.

> How could I debug this problem?

You will have to audit your firewall rules, understand them and then make appropriate changes.